# getContext error using chartjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jquery-context

I am following this tutorial `[chart.js][1]` and I get this error and this line

```
var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
```

where `$("#myChart")` stands for `<figure id="myChart" class="chart"></figure>`

throws this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLElement> has no method 'getContext'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, you have to use this instead

```
<canvas id="myChart" class="chart"></canvas>
```